# Intercepting XHR with JS

Tags: javascript

So I’m trying to intercept XHR, this is the code I’ve got:

```
let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
 console.log("Method: " + method);
 console.log("URL: " + url);

 return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

It works perfectly when I run it through chrome’s console tab but doesn’t work at all when I’m running it through an extension, from what I understand it can't work though an extension for some reasons.

My question is: I'm new to JS and I have no idea how to run this code, how can I run it on every open tab or if it's not possible how can I run this code?

Thanks :)

Comment: From where are you trying to run it with the extension? You may have to inject it into the page so that it runs with the proper context.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: This definitely is possible, userscripts are injected and can intercept this sort of thing all the time. Try out some of the methods in the canonical

Comment: I'm running it from the content_script, if that's what you're asking.
I don't get any error message, it just won't do anything.
I'll try to read more about injecting, thank you all :)